# How do I add an anchor-tag to window.location?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use that code here to reload the current page a user is on

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href">...
```

And additionally I want the user to jump to a given anchor-tag **#berechnen** - how would I do that in that case?

I tried with something like so

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href+#berechnen">
```

But of course that doesn't work. Do I need to save the window-location to a variable first and then add the #berechnen -string to it and then href to that variable?

Comment: I wonder will `location.href.replace(/(#[^#]+)?$/g, '#berechen')` work. Anchors are tricky in this aspect.

Comment: Assigning a ”new” location that only differs in the fragment is not going to cause a reload - that is a page-internal “jump” to a different position only. I think you’ll need to explicitly force the reload after jumping to / assigning the anchor part. `window.location.hash = "#foo"; window.location.reload();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In head:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function redirectToAnchor(anchor) {
    // We remove previous anchors from the current URL    
    var redirectToURL = document.URL.replace(/#.*$/, "");

    redirectToURL = redirectToURL + anchor
    window.location.href = redirectToURL;
    window.location.reload(true)
}
</script>
```

Then:

```
<a href="javascript:redirectToAnchor('#ANCHOR')">
```

Comment: Don't know if I just misunderstand it but this particular block var redirectToURL = '/questions/57922774/how-do-i-add-an-anchor-tag-to-window-location';
isn't what I am after. I really want to reload the current page without knowing the URL. All I know is the anchor-tags' name. Wouldn't var redirectToURL = '"';
basically then again be href="" ?

Comment: Updated the answer for handling not knowing the current URL. Still have to handle what happens if the current URL already has anchors.

Comment: And then I would do <a href="javascript:window.location.href"> ?

Comment: No, you wrap this code into a function and then call javascript:myFunction();

Comment: See updated code, no need to append ?random to the URL

Answer (score 1):

Personally I really dislike abusing the anchor tag by replacing its default behavior with JavaScript. By doing this, you break things like being able to open the link in a new tab, copying the link or bookmarking it.

One way you can keep this behavior and still reload the page after a click, is by adding the fragment to the `href` as you would do normally and in addition, you bind a JavaScript event that reloads the page when it is clicked. In that case you can simply use the `href` attribute to get the URL, and after you set the url, you reload the page. In the example below if the anchor has a `force-reload` class, it will also reload the page if you click on the anchor.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('force-reload') && e.target.nodeName === "A") {
    e.preventDefault();

    window.location = e.target.href;
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#content" class="force-reload">Click here</a>
```